# How To Hide/Toggle DIV When Select Input Is Clicked Or Changed

Tags: jquery, select, encoding

I want to Show/DISPLAY `.product-area-rule` when select bar has "SELECT SIZE".
And Hide/Remove `.product-area-rule` when select is switched on other option.

I have included an image preview with directions and more details on how I'd like it to work best... link is below. Thank you.

[Details with Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK1DR.jpg)

below Snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("select, select option").html().length > 0) {
    $('.product-area-rule').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="**product-area-rule**">SELECT A SIZE TO CONTINUE</div>

<select id="wsite-com-product-option-SIZE" name="SIZE">
  <option selected="selected">**SELECT SIZE**</option>
  <option>2 US</option>
  <option>4 US</option>
  <option>6 US</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('#wsite-com-product-option-SIZE').change(function(){
  if ($('#wsite-com-product-option-SIZE option:selected').text() === '**SELECT SIZE**') {
    $('.product-area-rule').show();
  } else {
    $('.product-area-rule').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-area-rule">SELECT A SIZE TO CONTINUE</div>

<select id="wsite-com-product-option-SIZE" name="SIZE">
  <option selected="selected">**SELECT SIZE**</option>
  <option>2 US</option>
  <option>4 US</option>
  <option>6 US</option>
</select>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I will give it a try now.